routerLink not navigating as expected
I have the following routes
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TeamsComponent } from './pages/teams/teams.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { BaseLayoutComponent } from './base-layout/base-layout.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        component: BaseLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'teams', component: TeamsComponent }
        ]
    },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' }
];

I have the following routerLink, which is part of my side menu navigation
<a routerLink="/teams" routerLinkActive="active">Teams</a>

further down the page I have the following
 <main class="py-10">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <router-outlet />
            </div>
        </main>

When trying to click on Teams, it doesn't appear clickable, when adding a (click)="teamsClicked()" I can write to the console, so I'm not sure what I'm doing here but it seems the router isn't working as expected, can anyone spot any issue here?
BaseLayoutComponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-layout',
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './base-layout.component.html',
  styleUrl: './base-layout.component.css'
})
export class BaseLayoutComponent {


  onClick() {
    console.log('Team link clicked');
  }

}


Make sure you have router-outlet set on BaseLayoutComponent HTML.
You can try setting the default route to the bottom.
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'teams', component: TeamsComponent },
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]

On the component where you have the routerLink in HTML. Make sure you have added RouterModule to the imports array of the component.
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [RouterModule], // <- changed here!
  standalone: true,
  ...
})
export class BaseLayoutComponent {


Tried changing the default route to bottom, problem still persisted, made sure to have RouterOutlet in base layout component too, I've also added the base layout component to the question

@CodeRatchet routeroutlet and routerlink both directives are required, so you can import RouterLink or just RouterModule into the BaseLayoutComponent this will fix the issue

Switched to RouterModule and it worked. Thanks, much appreciated.
